# Can't change property value in IE using JS

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've a little snippet code that doesn't work in IE only, tested in FF, Safari, Chrome, Rockmelt and all working.

JS:

```
document.forma.score.value = 12;
```

html:

```
<input name="score" id="score" type="text"/>
```

Comment: There's so much that can go wrong with name traversal. We need to see the rest of your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have encountered a well known [name/id mixup problem](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200802/beware_of_id_and_name_attribute_mixups_when_using_getelementbyid_in_internet_explorer/). Make sure that you have unique id's and that no id attribute value in your document is equal to name attribute values in that document.

On the other hand, I've jsfiddled a [small test](http://jsfiddle.net/GWqPR/). That worked in IE7-9. If it's IE6: that in this day and age should be an obsolete browser. If it's about another IE version, then look for other elements with name or id 'score' in your document.

Comment: Except that the OP isn't using `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @Matt: true. I still wanted to point the OP to that mixup, because he used equal name/id values.

Comment: I think I found another issue, I can't execute JS through: <body onload="cambiarScore()">

Comment: @Andres: looks like a whole new question to me ;~)

Answer (score 3):

How about getting the element directly?

```
document.getElementById('score').value = 12;
```

---

<sub>You may want to consider using one of the [many available cross-browser JavaScript libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) which remove 99.9% of the obnoxious, irritating, non-value-added differences between browsers. It really doesn't matter *which* library — Dojo, ExtJS,  jQuery, MooTools, Prototype, RightJS, YUI... just pick one that appeals to you. It'll save **a lot** of headaches.</sub>